# httpurlconnection NullPointerException in getInputStream

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, httpurlconnection

I am testing long polling in android by using httpurlconnection but application keep crashing with error nullpointerexception.

> `07-21 07:17:42.469: V/Online Connection(27092): Bufferd called
>   07-21 07:17:42.469: V/Online Connection(27092): data called
>   07-21 07:17:42.471: V/Online Connection(27092): Get data called
>   07-21 07:17:42.471: E/Online Connection(27092): Error calledSocket closed
>   07-21 07:17:42.472: V/Online Connection(27092): Get data called
>   07-21 07:17:42.473: V/Online Connection(27092): Connect called
>   07-21 07:17:42.479: V/Online Connection(27092): Connect called
>   07-21 07:17:42.832: V/Online Connection(27092): Bufferd called
>   07-21 07:17:42.832: V/Online Connection(27092): data calledok
>   07-21 07:17:44.147: V/Online Connection(27092): Bufferd called
>   07-21 07:17:44.147: V/Online Connection(27092): data called
>   07-21 07:17:44.148: V/Online Connection(27092): Get data called
>   07-21 07:17:44.149: V/Online Connection(27092): Connect called
>   07-21 07:17:44.152: E/Online Connection(27092): Error calledSocket closed
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-34364
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092): Process: in.briskjab.reactor, PID: 27092
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:632)
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092):    at in.bb.longpolling.onlineconnection.httpconnection(onlineconnection.java:89)
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092):    at in.bb.longpolling.onlineconnection.SGData(onlineconnection.java:39)
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092):    at in.bb.GActivity$6.run(GActivity.java:974)
>   07-21 07:17:44.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27092):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)`

Code:

```
> `public String SGData(String data,int option) { //Send And Get Data
    String newdataloc;
    try {
        newdataloc = URLEncoder.encode(data,"UTF-8");
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        Log.e("Online Connection","Error:Encoding="+e.getMessage());
    }

    return httpconnection(data,option);
}

private String httpconnection(String postData,int option){
    Log.v("Online Connection","Get data called");
    String webPage = "",resdata="";
    try{
           urlc = new URL(this.url);
           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlc.openConnection();
           Log.v("Online Connection","Connect called");
        if(option==1){ //only get data
            urlConnection.connect();// it gives error "already connected" if you are using it with post or get method.Uncomment and comment 'post and get method area' 
        }
        if(option==2){
            //POST METHOD AREA
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.getBytes().length));
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            out.write(postData.getBytes());
            out.close();
        }
        if(option==3){
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.getBytes().length));
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            out.write(postData.getBytes());
            out.close();
        }
           InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
           BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
           Log.v("Online Connection","Bufferd called");
           while ((resdata = reader.readLine()) != null){
              webPage += resdata + "\n";
           } 
           is.close();
           Log.v("Online Connection","data called" + webPage);
       } catch(IOException e){
           Log.e("Online Connection","Error called" + e.getMessage());
           }
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect(); 
    }
    return webPage;
}
calling Code:->
String mResponse=null;
                do{
                    mResponse = online_serlst.SGData("op=3&server_name="+mServerName+"&userid="+mUserid+"&color="+DeviceCurrentPlayer+"&lr="+lr+"&ld="+pd, 2);
                }while(!mResponse.toString().trim().equals("ok"));`
```

I am sending data from my game to the server if user click on submit button by using simple single request and keep checking for new update from server by using long polling if there is some new update.After 4 -5 minute application crashes with nullpointexception.using different thread for single request and long polling.

Testing application on android 4.4.2 moto g device.

Comment: Which is line number 39?

Comment: SGdata method in above code
public String SGData(String data,int option) {...........return httpconnection(data,option);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, this might be because it is closing/terminating connection pool. You are using 2 threads. One is for sending request to server & Second is for getting update response from server.

I think, if you just want to update your UI, you can prefer "Service Handler". This is best way to update your UI when you want to keep your UI updating so frequently.